Role of airflow-triggerer container in Airflow docker-compose
I'm trying to reduce the size of official Airflow docker-compose build. The question is about airflow-triggerer container. Seems like if I remove this container - nothing should change, because the scheduler triggers tasks. So, what is the role of airflow-triggerer?

The triggerer is employed to unblock the worker when running sensor or deferred jobs. It's important part of the architecture to running multiple jobs and avoid deadlock from running sensors and deferred jobs.

In case if I have LocalExecutor and don't have worker, is trigger handy? Here developer writes that "I decided to remove the airflow-trigger because it is a new airflow service specially made for asyncio event loop, that I was not going to use." - are the words about trigger is for asyncio true?

For your usecase, you can remove it and see if the performance of your pipeline degrades or you run into a deadlock. Triggers are implemented as async functions and run in the asyncio event loop. I want to assume that you don't use triggers in your tasks or deferred jobs at the moment. If you use or plan to use them, then the triggerer should be started to run those triggers. Airflow infers the appropriate runner is inferred to run the task.
